# Merge list elements of one single list by name in R

Tags: r, list, merge

I have one list with a large number of elements (supposed to be an inverse index in the end).

- All elements are numeric vectors with a different length.
- The name of an element occurs multiple times

```
> par.list
$NAMEA
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10

$NAMEB
[1] 6

$NAMEB
[1] 11 12 13 16 17

$NAMEA
[1] 14 15 18 19 20
```

What I look for is an efficient was such that I get

```
> merged.list
$NAMEA
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10 14 15 18 19 20

$NAMEB
[1] 6 11 12 13 16 17
```

I am sure that there is an easy way to do it but I just don't happen to find the right thread here, so I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may `stack` the named `list` to a two column data.frame and `split`

```
with(stack(par.list), split(values, ind))
```

-output

```
$NAMEA
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10 14 15 18 19 20

$NAMEB
[1]  6 11 12 13 16 17
```

#### data

```
par.list <- list(NAMEA = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10), NAMEB = 6, NAMEB = c(11L, 
12L, 13L, 16L, 17L), NAMEA = c(14L, 15L, 18L, 19L, 20L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option with `lapply` -

```
uq_names <- unique(names(par.list))

setNames(lapply(uq_names, function(x) 
        unlist(par.list[names(par.list) == x], use.names = FALSE)), uq_names)

#$NAMEA
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 10 14 15 18 19 20

#$NAMEB
#[1]  6 11 12 13 16 17
```